# passing data between two sibling components in angular 7

Tags: angular

Here the requirement is i need to display the user who logged in, in a home, for that i have a logincomponent , homecomponent and for data transfer i am using a service called dataService.ts,for me the data is coming up to dataService.ts but it is not coming to homecomponent

My code

imported dataservice in loginComponent

this.userName consists of username who logged in

login component:

```
this.ds.sendMessage(this.userName);
```

dataService:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService
{
    constructor()
    {
    }

    private apiData = new Subject<Object>();
    public apiData$ = this.apiData.asObservable();

    sendMessage(message: Object)
    {
        this.apiData.next(message);
        console.log(message);
    }
}
```

homecoponent:

```
ngOnInit();
{
    console.log('in homecomponent');
    this.DataService.apiData$
        .subscribe(
            message =>
            {
                console.log(message);
            }
        );
}
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: which providers you included service means module level or component level

Comment: component level

Comment: Have you considered using ```BehaviorSubject``` instead of ```Subject```.

Comment: yes first i used behaviorSubject and then i changed it to Subject

Comment: inject service in module , it will solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

It is likely, that both DataServices are not the same. Please make sure you provide the service on a higher level (Module, not Component) or use a store both services are referring to.

Answer (score 0):

Create a data service that is responsible for broadcasting the value you pass:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {

  private value: string;
  listeners = [];

  constructor() {
    this.value = '';
  }

  onDataChange(fn) {
    this.listeners.push(fn);
  }

  set setData(value: string) {
    this.value = value;
    this.listeners.forEach((fn) => {
      fn(value);
    });
  }
}
```

In each of your component where you want to perform communication, inject the data service.

`constructor(private dataService: DataService) {}`

You can set the value of the data in a component like so:

`this.dataService.setData= 'New value';`

You can then subscribe to the value change event of the data service in a different component on `ngOnInit`:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.dataService.onDataChange((value) => {
         this.data = value;
    });
}
```

[Live Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z5va6z)

Comment: when we do like this  while we are setting the data    we get error    like this                   
        Type 'String' is not assignable to type 'string'.
  'string' is a primitive, but 'String' is a wrapper object. Prefer using 'string' when possible.ts(2322)

Comment: Make sure you're not using 'String' anywhere in your app. I've updated my answer to include a live demo.

Comment: if we did like this the data is coming upto service and then it is not displaying in home component,It is displaying just as a empty string

Comment: Did you subscribe to data change event of the service in home component's `ngOnInit` event? Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: I followed this approach to pass data between 2 child components (let's call them A and B).  The problem I'm encountering is that subscribing to the data service in ngOnInit only updates the child component (A) subscribing to the service once.  If child component B makes any further updates to a variable in the data service, changes to that data service variable isn't picked up by the data service subscription in child component A.  How to keep the data service subscription in child component A live until the point we unsubscribe in ngDestroy lifecycle?  Call it in ngDoCheck instead?

Answer (score 0):

hi you can have a look at this [fire-base](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/) post
at this post the author provide some explanation on passing data between components at any type (siblings - siblings, parent - child, child - child ...) good lock