# Angular 5 - Asynchronous Service Calls in two different components (First Method Not waiting for DB response)

Tags: angular, asynchronous, angular5, angular-observable

I have to perform two different DB transactions on a single (click) event.

First Call : Save Data to DB.

Second Call : Get the first call's saved data from DB

These calls are separated in two different components and deal with one common DB Table.

My approach is below :

**First Component TS :**

```
ngOnDestroy(){ this.saveData(); }
```

**Second Component TS :**

```
ngOnInit(){ this.getSavedData(); }
```

**Service call for First Method to Execute :**

```
 saveData(obj) {
    return this.http.post(environment.appUrl + 'saveDataApi', obj).toPromise()
      .then(res => <any>res); }
```

Both these methods are getting triggered sequentially as coded. But my issue is that `this.getSavedData();` completes its DB transaction earlier before **Save** method's DB transaction is completed & response is returned.

I need that the service call for 'Save' method should wait for DB response and then proceed to 'Get' method in other component.

In short : `this.getSavedData();` should not be executed until and unless `this.SaveData();` completes its **entire** execution returning a response.

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you show me your "getSavedData()" method and how you call that method ?

Comment: TS :
getSavedData() {
    this.dataService.getSavedData(this.obj).then(data => {
     if (data.lstRespObj[0] != null && data.lstRespObj[0].length > 0) {
          this.fetchedData = data.lstRespObj[0];
         }
     });
  }
  
Service : 
getSavedData(obj) {
    return this.http.post(environment.appUrl + 'getDataApi', obj).toPromise()
      .then(res => <any>res);
  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a service called `data.service.ts` (name as you wish) to handle the HTTP call. Make a `saveData` method. Call that from the first component (although I'm not sure if ngOnDestroy is the best place to make a call like that):

```
ngOnDestroy(){ this.dataService.saveData(); }
```

Implement your service in a way that it emits the result from the service when the response suceeded:

```
@Injectable()
export class DataService {
  private _data$ = new ReplaySubject(1);
  public data$ = this._data$.asObservable();

  saveData(obj) {
    return this.http.post(environment.appUrl + 'saveDataApi', obj).pipe(
      tap(res => this._data$.next(res)
    )
      .toPromise()
      .then(res => <any>res); 
  }
}
```

In your second component, subscribe to the service's data$ Observable:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.dataSubscription = this.dataService.data$.subscribe(() => [..])
}
```

And don't forget to unsubscribe when you leave the component:

```
ngOnDestroy() {
  this.dataSubscription.unsubscribe();
}

Or bind data$ to your template directly using the async pipe.
Maybe you should consider adding a state management framework to your application, like ngRX, but that is a bigger jump.
```

Comment: Hey.. This is working quite good but my 'Get' calls are increasing +1 if I do the same thing again in running session.. Eg: Save(); Get(); -- Save(); Get(); Get(); --- Save(); Get(); Get(); Get();...... Can you tell me a way to unsubscribe this thing once 'Get' is finished?

Comment: I'm not destroying the component though.. need some other place to unsubscribe it..

Answer (score 0):

If the component that is responsible for getting the data is a child component to the one that saves it, I would recommend [pass data from parent to child with input binding](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction).

Otherwise, you could create a shared service to notify sibling components.

[See my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54941453/2093029)

Comment: In my case, Component that gets the data is the parent component..I just want to pause the Angular workflow until the Save method hits the DB Stored Proc and comes back with a response.. I have tried setting a timeout but that's a temporary escape!

Answer (score -1):

You may need to call onDestroy something like following code.

```
  async ngOnDestroy() {
    const res = await this.saveData(); 
  }
```

Comment: Tried.. still behaving the same way.. getSavedData() is completed first :(

Comment: This does nothing, Angular will not wait on the Promise before proceeding.